# PHP / Laravel echo HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel

So i have the following value:

```
$content = "<ol><li>AbC</li></ol><p>sd</p>"
```

Now I wish to display this on my `page.blade.php`

But I am not quite sure how to do it. I have attempted with:

```
{{$content}}
```

But as expected it just prints the HTML and does not actually inject it.

So my question is how do I inject the HTML?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following-

```
{!!$content!!}
```

`{{ }}` will result in auto escape of string.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing variable to your view. Then you can access this by 2 ways:

```
{{!! $content !!}}
```

or

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Comment: `{{!!` is an error, it's `{!!` or `{{`. Also, you shouldn't have to use `<?php ... ?>` tags in `.blade`; goes against the point of using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 {! html_entities_decode($content) !}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site and thanks for your answer. Maybe you might want to edit your post to expand upon what this is doing and why this solves the problem? It'll help the poster and other people who come across this question understand what is happening better.

Comment: okay thanks for your comment i'll keep in my mind it for next answers and posts. So Thank you :)